# How to reset local orientation / frame of reference of object created from array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, transforms

I have the following setup:

A bezier curve and an object, originally with all its transforms cleared to identity.

I then proceed to do the following:

1. Add an array modifier to the object to replicate it along the curve.
2. Add a Curve modifier to have the array instances follow the path of the curve.[image][image]
3. Apply both modifiers to the object.
4. In Edit mode, I separate the object by loose parts, so that I end up with individual objects all along the curve.

At this point what I notice is that each object's local origin / frame of reference is no longer orthonormal to the object in question but rather, each object's origin is the center origin of the original object I used as the source for the modifiers.

For example, here's one of the objects along the path. Notice how its origin's position / orientation are really the one of the original object in the center of the world: This is before doing `Origin to Geometry` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
[image]

And this is after trying to center the origin on the object:
[image]

Notice how the origin is now 'centered' on the objet but still oriented to the center of the world.

In other words, I now have this:

[image]

But I need something like this: (I achieved the origin pointing this way by switching from 'local' to 'view' mode, but the origin itself is still wrong in reality).

[image]

That is, the origin should be pointing along the path.

Comment: You can switch `Transformation Orientation` option to `Normal` (`Alt` + `Tab`) and use it pressing `G`, then selecting desired axis with twice pressing `X` or `Y` or `Z`.

Comment: I know how to switch to the global / local transform and how to translate / 'grab' stuff. The problem is not that but that, as seen in the screenshot, the local transform is messed up; the green arrow in the picture should be pointing along the black path line.

Comment: I pointed out a workaround to this problem which is that you don't use Local Coordinates rather than Normal Coordinates instead. If using last ones, it'll be possible to grab faces of your mesh along the curve, because the green arow, or `Y` axis, will be pointed that way. The local coordinates inherited adjacent coordinates of the original mesh, and there's no way to 'reset them', unless some weird tricks, like combining this mesh with another one, that have local coordinates as you need

Comment: hmm. So there's no way? then, can you think of another way of ending up with several objects along a path each with their own transforms set in the way I need them? The reason why I need this is because then I export this whole thing to Unity and animate the objects inside a game I'm working on. I added more detail to my question just in case. And thanks BTW for your input :)

Comment: Are all those objects along the path different meshes ? And you want to say that you need Local coordinates 'reseted' because of game ?

Comment: Right now there's 3 different kinds: the one I'm showing is a sort of waypoint  / chevron. Then I repeat the process at different spacings for 2 other kinds of objects which are 'traps' that essentially rotate continuously about their 'forward' axis and have a segment that 'kills' the vehicle if the vehicle racing doesn't doge. The main problem with the axis being the way they are is that I can't animate the traps rotating 360 about their forward axis. And I went for this approach  because the track is long (several Kms), so I can't individually place 60+ to 100 objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25006/discussion-between-saldavonschwartz-and-mr-zak).